# What paint for a tire swing?

Tags: paint

I just bought a big used tire and hung it as a tire swing. I pressure washed it, but it still sheds a little black residue. I'd love to seal it/paint it, but am not sure what would stick to a tire and not crack over time in the sun. Any recommendations?

Comment: I have paint pens that stick to rubber (dive gear)  uni paint ,px-20 it is an oil based paint not sure if you can find more on the type but it holds up over hundreds of dives.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the type of tire dressing like auto detailers use to spruce up the sidewalls of the tires on cars/trucks. You can find this online by searching for "tire dressing" or "tire shine". It should also be available at your local auto parts store.

My experience with products of this type is that they give the rubber of the tire a surface that is glossy look and a smooth feel. Exposure to sun and weather will likely require re-application from time to time but should certainly reduce the amount of "rub off" coming off the tire.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try two things. First, I'd wax it with auto wax. This will result in a dry finish that probably won't rub off more than the tire itself did.

If that doesn't work, try polishing the surface with a torch. Maybe by melting it slightly you'll get a more sealed finish.

Answer (score 0):

A few companies (e.g., Krylon and Rust-OLeum that I know of) make paint specifically designed for plastics.  They're for uses such as refinishing lawn furniture.  They're tough, flexible, and bond with the plastic.

I have no idea how well it would bond with a tire since tires are designed to not be affected by the hydrocarbon solvents that are used as vehicle fuels and additives.  But the paint is readily available at big hardware chains, and it would be relatively inexpensive to try.